# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pycaret.time_series'

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, pycaret

I've seen similar questions, but no solutions for this problem.

I'm using Google Colab:

```
!pip install pycaret
```

And this:

```
import time
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


from pycaret.datasets import get_data
#from pycaret.time_series import TSForecastingExperiment
from pycaret.time_series import *
```

The last line returns the error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pycaret.time_series'

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please follow the instructions here: https://github.com/pycaret/pycaret#-pycaret-time-series-module-beta

Specifically, for the time being, the Time Series module needs to be installed separately in its own environment (i.e. not together with the main `pycaret` package), using:

```
!pip install pycaret-ts-alpha
```

Comment: funny, I was following the tutorial here: https://nbviewer.org/github/pycaret/pycaret/blob/master/examples/time_series/forecasting/time_series_101.ipynb
Anyway, it is working now